# BTC/USDT trading on binance

Tags: trading, binance

I have an account on binance and i would like to trade on the platform in the BTC/USDT market. However something does not add up to me.

Lets say at 1100 HRS 1 BTC = 6154 USDT and at 1200 HRD 1 BTC = 6180 USDT

I should therefore be having more bitcoins if i sell when 1 BTC = 6180 USDT but this does not seem to be the case. I have attached the graphic to demonstrate what i mean.

[image]

What is exactly happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your screenshot is showing: You have set the amount of USDT to 30 in each case, *so at the higher price, you will need to sell less BTC in order to get 30 USDT*. This is different than setting the amount to a constant amount of BTC in both cases, and seeing the difference in USDT.

The math in your example:

`(1 BTC/6180 USDT)(30 USDT) = (0.004854.. BTC)`

`(1 BTC/6154 USDT)(30 USDT) = (0.004875.. BTC)`

The math, assuming you're buying/selling 0.005 BTC at the prices listed:

`(6180 USDT/1 BTC)(0.005 BTC) = (30.90 USDT)`

`(6154 USDT/1 BTC)(0.005 BTC) = (30.77 USDT)`